# How to detect what part of the 3D object has been selected(touched by the user) using Xcode ARKit(Scenekit)?

Tags: scenekit, ios11, arkit, xcode9-beta5

I have developed a POC using **ARKit - SceneKit** using https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2017/PlacingObjects.zip. I have implemented a feature using which user can change colours of the 3D object after placing it in floor using camera. I want to allow user to select the part of the model(**with highlighting the part**) as they touch the respective part using camera, detect what part has been selected and show the colour options to the user.

Right now i am allowing to change the colour of 0th object alone(**0th object of selected Xcode .scn file**) instead of user selecting particular parts like below,

```
 self.virtualObjectManager.lastUsedObject?.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].geometry?.firstMaterial?.multiply.contents
 = UIColor(red: 233/255, green: 136/255, blue: 215/255, alpha: 1)
```

How to implement this? Is there any way i can detect what part of the model user has touched(**For example**. If a cot with bed is displayed, i want to recognise if user touched cot or bed before showing colour options)

Comment: Have a look at doing a SCNHitTest: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnhittestresult . You can perform a hit on the screen based on a CGPoint (derived from a touch) and see whether any nodes were found. The node that you find would be a part of your .scn file, so you can then manipulate it's material. If you wanted to get the whole object, then get the parent. 
Can give you some more specific help if you have a go at it yourself and update the question.